# How to convert camel case to lower case with underscores in a REST API?

Tags: java, openapi, quarkus, microprofile

I am using Quarkus and Microprofile OpenAPI to map entities in REST APIs.
I can convert my camel case named properties to lower case with underscores in the following way:

```
@Schema(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;
```

However it is inconvenient as I have to do this everywhere across the project.

**Question:** Is there a way to do it automatically for all properties without having to specify the mapping in the annotation?

I went through the documentation of Quarkus and Microprofile but haven't found how it can be achieved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to make this behaviour the default one, you have to configure this in the object mapper that is responsible for serialization/deserialization of objects to json.
In Quarkus, you can use either Jackson or JsonB for object mapping.

For Jackson, you can control the behaviour of field names using [PropertyNamingStrategy](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.html) which you want to set to `SNAKE_CASE`. To set this globally, create an `ObjectMapperCustomizer` like so:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy;
import io.quarkus.jackson.ObjectMapperCustomizer;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class ObjectMapperConfig implements ObjectMapperCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
         objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE)
    }
}
```

You can control many more aspects of serialization e.g. ignore unknown props during deserialization, date formatting, etc.

You need to have a dep to `quarkus-resteasy-jackson`:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
   <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If you want to use JsonB (`quarkus-resteasy-jsonb`) then you can try it with the following `JsonbConfigCustomizer`

```
import io.quarkus.jsonb.JsonbConfigCustomizer;

import javax.inject.Singleton;
import javax.json.bind.JsonbConfig;
import javax.json.bind.config.PropertyNamingStrategy;
@Singleton
public class JsonBCustomizer implements JsonbConfigCustomizer {

    public void customize(JsonbConfig config) {
        config.withPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
    }
}
```

Comment: `PropertyNamingStrategy` is now deprecated. The one to use now is `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategies`

Answer (score -1):

I found this in the openapi doc :

> You can control how the Schema property names are dumped by setting
> the micronaut.openapi.property.naming.strategy system property. It
> accepts one of the following jackson's PropertyNamingStrategy: -
> SNAKE_CASE, - UPPER_CAMEL_CASE, - LOWER_CAMEL_CASE, - LOWER_CASE and -
> KEBAB_CASE.

For further details see [Hibernate 5 Naming Strategy Configuration](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-naming-strategy) by [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/author/baeldung/).

Comment: It is not about ORM. It is about mapping class fields to josn properties.

Comment: I found this in the openapi doc :
You can control how the Schema property names are dumped by setting the micronaut.openapi.property.naming.strategy system property. It accepts one of the following jackson's PropertyNamingStrategy: - SNAKE_CASE, - UPPER_CAMEL_CASE, - LOWER_CAMEL_CASE, - LOWER_CASE and - KEBAB_CASE.